# Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'String'

Tags: swift

```
class C{
 var b:[String]?
 subscript(i:Int)->String?{
  get{
   return b?[i]
  }
  set{
   b?[i] = newValue! // notice the unwrapped “!” here
  }
 }
}
```

In the code, I put a exclamation mark "!" to unwrap the `newValue`,
Because `newValue` is the same type of the return value of subscript which is String?.
If I don't put the exclamation mark "!" it will report error:
   "

> error: cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type '`String`'      `b?[i] = newValue`

"
Question:  `b?[i]` is obviously an optional String value String?, how come it is of type String.
I wonder it was a bad error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You property `b` is indeed an optional *array*, but its member elements are *not* optionals. Hence, when attempting to assign a new value to an existing member, the new value must be of concrete type `String`, and not the optional type `String?`.

```
// this is an Optional array, with non-optional elements
var foo: [String]? = ["foo"]

let optStr: String? = "bar"
let nonOptStr = "bar"

// ok, nonOptStr is not an optional
foo?[0] = nonOptStr

// as for 'nonOptStr', we need to unwrap
// it prior to attempting to assign it as a 
// replacement member of 'foo'
if let str = optStr {
    foo?[0] = str
}
```

Also, avoid explicit unwrapping, and consider validating the index prior to using it. E.g.:

```
class C {
    var b: [String]?
    subscript(i: Int) -> String? {
        get {
            if b?.indices.contains(i) ?? false { return b?[i] }
            return nil            
        }
        set {
            if b?.indices.contains(i) ?? false, let newValue = newValue {
                b?[i] = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your var b: [String]? is an optional array. However the string inside is not optional. If you changed it to: var b: [String?]? then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, I found myself with this exact error after doing a split on a string and ended up printing out both variables.  That clarified that I was trying to assign a two element variable to an indexed array that contained a string.  So, that is the source of the error, which is essentially saying your trying to assign two elements of an array into a string inside your other array.  Well, that makes sense out of the error.
Algorithmically it is:
1) array1[0] = array2Item1, array2Item2

That's why this was fine:
2) array1 = array2Item1, array2Item2

but the above was not.

So, the correct thing to do is 2) and then assign it by index:

array1 = array2Item1, array2Item2

array3 = array1[0] to do what I thought I was doing in 1).

Just another explanation for any others who venture here.